# random number with ratio 1:2

Tags: algorithm, math, random, numbers, distribution

I have to generate  two random sets of matrices
Each containing   3 digit numbers   ranging from 2 - 10

like that

matrix 1:  994,878,129,121

matrix 2:  272,794,378,212

the numbers in both matrices have to be  greater then 100 and  less then  999

BUT

the  mean for both matrices has to be in the ratio  of  1:2  or 2:3  what ever constraint the user inputs

my math skills are kind  of limited so any ideas how do i make this happen?

Comment: Does there have to be exactly four numbers in each?

Comment: numbers can range from  2 sets to 10 depending on the input

Comment: lolz  no  it's for my research project want to automate this process

Comment: Okay, you can adapt my answer to any number of values, as long as you know how many in advance.

Comment: How is a research project NOT homework?

Comment: Do the *observed means* have to respect that ratio for each run, or is it sufficient that the ratio averages out over several runs?  If it's the former and the sets are small, the 2nd set is not going to be very random as there'll be only a few combinations that will satisfy the ratio given the 1st.

Comment: Also, what about the shape of the distribution?  Is it supposed to be uniform within a set, or normally distributed?  Perhaps you can give more details on why you need to do this that might help to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you have to know how many numbers are in each list.  I'm assuming from your example that there are four numbers in each.

1. Fill the first list with four random numbers.

   Calculate the mean of the first list.

   Multiply the mean by 2 or by 3/2, whichever the user input.  This is the required mean of the second list.

   Multiply by 4.  This is the required total of the second list.

   Generate 3 random numbers.

   Subtract the total of the three numbers in step 5 from the total in step 4.  This is the fourth number for the second list.

   If the number in step 6 is not in the correct range, start over from step 5.

Note that the last number in the second list is not truly random, since it's based on the other values in the list.

Comment: I tried the solution  but its almost impossible to get the right value the program keeps on looping
expectedTotal: 4322
second matrix: 537,178,569
Sum of the matrix : 1284
fourth number: 3038

is there something i am missing

Comment: How are you seeding the random number generator?

Comment: first matrix 100- 499

second 100-999

Comment: I mean, what are you using to get random numbers?  Like, in Java, you'd use Random rand = new Random();, then use rand.nextInt(1000);.  How are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of random numbers, s1.

```
s1= [ random.randint(100,999) for i in range(n) ]
```

For some other set, s2, to have a different mean it's simply got to have a different range.  Either you select values randomly from a different range, or you filter random values to get a different range.

No matter how many **random** numbers you select from the range 100 to 999, the mean is always just about 550.  The odds of being a different value are exactly the normal distribution probabilities on either side of the mean.

You can't have a radically different mean with values selected from the same range.

Comment: range has to be the same, the mean has to be different.

Comment: Sorry, but if the range is the same, and the numbers are truly random, the expected value of the mean will be the same. Pick any two from (same range, random, different means).

Comment: @Brent Longborough: The original question is either misstated or is a logical contradiction.

Comment: This is only true for uniformly distributed random numbers.  You can easily have two different beta distributions on the same range with different means.